# Dual boot Kali on windows 8.1

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware

I am trying to dual boot Kali Linux with Windows 8.1 using VMware. I download the VM torrent from [offensive security](http://offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vmware-arm-image-download/) - http://images.kali.org/Kali-Linux-2.0.0-vm-amd64.7z
I then extract the files.

I see no ISO to actually put into my "Create a new virtual machine" line. I see a lot of files such as

- Kali-Linux-2.0.0-vm-amd64.nvram
- Kali-Linux-2.0.0-vm-amd64 Kali-Linux-2.0.0-vm-amd64.vmxf
- Kali-Linux-2.0.0-vm-amd64-s008

Comment: VMWare Player* Or will I need something like pro/fusion/workstation instead of just vmware player?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should make clear whether you want to dual-boot (having two operating systems installed on your physical machine and deciding on boot which of them you want to boot up) or virtualize (have one host system (e.g. Windows) and have a virtual machine running on top of it running Kali).

The image you downloaded seems to be a VMware image, which can be imported into your VMware Player (if you want to have it running in a VM).

If you intend to dual-boot with Windows, you have to download the Kali Linux ISO ( https://www.kali.org/downloads/ ) and either burn it to DVD or create a bootable USB device. As far as I remember it can install a boot loader like GRUB for you which realizes the boot prompt which system you want to boot.

In addition you can run Kali Linux in Live mode. That means that you boot it from DVD/USB and do not change your system. Just remember to save anything you want to keep before shutting down the live system as it completely runs in your RAM and everything is lost after it is shut down.